# How do I get the query to display both results?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query statement

```
$moc_query = $database->database_query("SELECT gg_congress_members.id,
  gg_congress_members.member_fname,gg_congress_members.member_lname,
  gg_congress_members.member_state,gg_congress_members.member_party,
  gg_congress_members.member_title
  FROM
    gg_congress_members
  WHERE (member_title = 'Sen' AND member_state='$user_state')
        OR (member_title = 'Representative' AND
            member_district = '$user_district'
            AND member_state='$user_state') ")
or die(mysql_error());
```

My code:

```
if ($user_info["user_id"])
{
    $senators .= "<h2>Your Senators are</h2>";
    $senators .= "<ol>";

    $reps .= "<h2>Your Congressperson is</h2>";
    $reps .= "<ol>";

    $rep_count = 0;
    foreach ($mocs as $moc)
    {
        print_r ($mocs);
        $moc_title = $moc['moc_title'];
        $moc_fname = $moc['moc_fname'];
        $moc_lname = $moc['moc_lname'];
        $moc_party = $moc['moc_party'];
        $moc_state = $moc['moc_state'];

        if ($moc['moc_title'] == "Sen")
        {
            $senators .= "<li>$moc_fname $moc_lname - $moc_party ($moc_state)</li> ";           
        }

        if ($moc['moc_title'] == "Representative" )
        {
            $rep_count++;
            $reps .= "<li>$moc_fname $moc_lname - $moc_party ($moc_state)</li> ";
        }

    }
}
```

It's only displaying the reps on not the senators. If I remove the part about the representatives in the query then it does show the senators.

Comment: Why is your code indented *randomly*? Indentation is important, it has strong semantic meaning and if you want other people to read your code and help you, you should take the time to do it right.

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect between columns selected and field names in the result set. column member_title vs. 'moc_title' in the later code. Unless there's some translation going on in the code you're not showing, I'm surprised this works at all.

Comment: I suggest you echo out `$moc_query` to verify your bind values are correct. (You don't show that portion of your code.) Also, the column names returned by the query don't match the index values for `$moc`. (Again, you don't show that portion of your code.) And we don't see where the contents of $reps or $senators is being output to the page. (And you don't show that portion of your code either.)

Answer (score 0):

How are you binding your parameters?  I wonder if having the same name twice is somehow messing things up (although it shouldn't).  If removing the reps shows the senators, then perhaps something like this would work:

```
SELECT gg_congress_members.id,
   gg_congress_members.member_fname,
   gg_congress_members.member_lname,
   gg_congress_members.member_state,
   gg_congress_members.member_party, 
   gg_congress_members.member_title  
FROM gg_congress_members  
WHERE member_state='$user_state' AND 
   ((member_title = 'Sen') OR 
   (member_title = 'Representative' AND member_district = '$user_district'))
```

Good luck.

Comment: I *really* hope those values are [escaped correctly](http://bobby-tables.com/php).